# Function of "[tool.setuptools.packages] find = {}" in pyproject.toml

Tags: python, setuptools, pypi, python-packaging

The GitLab instructions for packaging a Python project for the package registry instruct users to create a pyproject.toml file with the following contents:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=61.0"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "mypypipackage"
version = "0.0.1"
authors = [
    { name="Example Author", email="author@example.com" },
]
description = "A small example package"
requires-python = ">=3.7"
classifiers = [
   "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
   "Operating System :: OS Independent",
]

[tool.setuptools.packages]
find = {}
```

Can anyone explain what the function of `find = {}` in the bottom section is? The GitLab guide doesn't explain and I can't seem to find any documentation for this.

The .toml file works just fine as instructed of course, but it also seems to work fine without including the `[tool.setuptools.packages]` section altogether.

Comment: This is a pretty useful [discussion of the issues with package auto-discovery](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/discussions/3346 "python package auto discovery")

Answer (score 5):

It is a [*`setuptools`* custom discovery directive](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html#custom-discovery), using here the `pyproject.toml`  syntax.

> If the automatic discovery does not work for you (e.g., you want to include in the distribution top-level packages with reserved names such as `tasks`, `example` or `docs`, or you want to exclude nested packages that would be otherwise included), you can use the provided tools for package discovery

```ini
[tool.setuptools.packages]
find = {}  # Scanning implicit namespaces is active by default
# OR
find = {namespaces = false}  # Disable implicit namespaces
```

> `find:` (`find_packages()` or `find = {}`) takes a source directory and two lists of package name patterns to exclude and include, and then returns a list of `str` representing the packages it could find.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you. Wish the pyproject.toml documentation was better and indicated where to find stuff like this.

Comment: I agree, this is not readily available.